# How to read specific lines from a .txt file?

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I am creating a program which can create a playlist and play music from it. I have a listbox and a button beside and with the following code.

```
Dim MusicFiles() As String
Public ListOfMusicFiles As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        MusicFiles = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
    End If
    Try
        For Each Item In MusicFiles
            Dim ItemSplit() = Item.Split("\"c)
            Dim ItemLast As String = ItemSplit(ItemSplit.Count - 1)
            ItemLast = ItemLast.Remove(ItemLast.Count - 4, 4)
            ListOfMusicFiles.Add(ItemLast, Item)
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

The above code puts the names of the desired music files but I need to store this somewhere, somehow. I need to create a .txt file and maybe have the name of the music file in the first line and the location in the second line. So, I need to read two lines and add them to the

```
listofmusicfiles
```

(the dictionary that I created)

then, I can import the files into the listbox. 
Any help would be appreciated. The application is still in the development process, so if you have a WHOLE different way of doing that, or an easier or more efficient way, that would be great :)

Comment: so what is your question, how to READ specific lines from a file (title) or how to WRITE the dictionary contents to a file (msg text)

Comment: Have you looked at System.IO.File.ReadAllLines and System.IO.File.WriteAllLines ?

Comment: You may want to consider using something more standard and flexible, such as XML.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to `How to read specific lines from a .txt file?`:

```
#Region " Read TextFile Line "

' [ Read TextFile Line Function ]
'
' // By Elektro H@cker
'
' Examples :
'
' MsgBox(Read_TextFile_Line("C:\File.txt", 1))
' Dim str As String = Read_TextFile_Line("C:\File.txt", 3)

Private Function Read_TextFile_Line(ByVal File As String, ByVal Line_Number As Long) As String

    Dim Lines() As String = {String.Empty}
    Dim Line_Length As Long = 0

    Try
        Lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(File)
        Line_Length = Lines.LongLength - 1
        Return Lines(Line_Number - 1)

    Catch ex As IO.FileNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("File not found: ""{0}""", _
                                      File), _
                        Nothing, _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Attempted to read line {0}, but ""{1}"" has {2} lines.", _
                                      Line_Number, _
                                      File, _
                                      Line_Length + 1), _
                        Nothing, _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                        MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(String.Format("{0}: {1}", _
                                          ex.Message, _
                                          ex.StackTrace))

    Finally
        Lines = Nothing
        Line_Length = Nothing

    End Try

    Return Nothing

End Function

#End Region
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question, "so if you have a WHOLE different way of doing that, or an easier or more efficient way, that would be great", use a dataset.

```
    'You only need to define your data once
    Dim ds As New DataSet 'I like saving datasets to file as opposed to datatables. Plus you get the advantage of have muliple tables if you need.
    Dim dt As New DataTable 'The table will hold you data, you can have multiple tables for storing different types of data
    'Add what ever columns you what to the table
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("FileName", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("FileLocation", GetType(String)))
    'Add the table to the dataset
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    'Now you can add records to your table
    Dim DR As DataRow
    DR = dt.NewRow 'This builds a new record with the schema from your table, but you still have to fill in the data
    'fill in the data columns you wanted
    DR("FileName") = "..Your file name here.."
    DR("FileLocation") = "..Your location here.."
    'Now add the new row to your table
    dt.Rows.Add(DR)


    'Then, whenever you want, you can save to your HD like this:
    ds.WriteXml("Your File Name", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema) 'XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema IS IMPORTANT

    'And can can read from the HD like this
    ds.ReadXml("Your File Name")
```

Comment: But I can't read the different rows separately, right?
I want the name to be displayed and the location separately..

Comment: I dont know what you mean. It is data that you can query or itterate through or read specific rows or columns or whatever you want. You can even easily sort the data. This is pretty much the most flexability you can have.

Comment: What I wanted to do was to create a simple playlist. I click on one of the items from the playlist, and the music plays. And when I close the application and open the application again, the music files should still be there.. Any ideas?

Comment: But when I do something like.. 
Label1.text = ds.readxml("C:\Test.xml"). The text in the label becomes "1"..

Comment: Perhaps you should look into how dataset and datatable work. You cant put tons of data into it and expect to get it out into a single label. Imagine the datatable is like a worksheet in excel. It has rows and columns. You need to get a value from a specific row AND column, not put the whole excel file into a single label.